# I have output of a script I wrote and need to convert to a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, csv

How do I output the information from this script to a csv file ? anything helps.

Below is a script I wrote to that uses the stat command and the du command to output information on files in subdirectories for archiving purposes. The client wanted the output of this information which is the file name, the size of the file, the created, accessed, modified, and changed date of the file to determine which files they want to archive and which will stay put. Is there a way to send this output information to a csv file or excel file ?

```
echo "Please type in the directory"
read directory
for entry in "$directory"/*
do

    modDate=$(stat -c %y "$entry") modDate1=$(stat -c %x "$entry") modDate2=$(stat -c %z "$entry") modDate3=$(du -sh "$entry"|awk '{print $1}') modDate4=$(stat -c %w "$entry") modDate5=$(stat -c %n "$entry")

    modDate=${modDate%% *}

    modDate1=${modDate1%% *}

    modDate2=${modDate2%% *}

    modDate4=${modDate4%% *}

    echo File Name:$modDate5  Size:$modDate3  Created:$modDate4  Accessed:$modDate1  Modified:$modDate  Changed:$modDate2
done
```

the output example of this script on terminal is stated as below, the output is what I would like to be transferred to a csv file. Thank you

EXECUTING SCRIPT

```
root@xizsdap1x:/home/o722823a# ./find.sh

Please type in the directory
READS
/sasdata/userdata01

OUTPUT
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db1 Size:153G Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2018-05-31 Changed:2018-05-31

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db2 Size:1.9T Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2020-04-21 Changed:2022-02-01

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db3 Size:819G Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2017-10-27 Changed:2018-11-13

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db4 Size:702G Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2018-04-03 Changed:2018-05-26

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/dbqa Size:2.7T Created:2020-08-05 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2021-05-22 Changed:2022-09-06

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/proj22 Size:712G Created:2018-08-07 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2018-04-03 Changed:2020-02-28

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/proj26 Size:627G Created:2022-05-25 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2022-06-03 Changed:2022-06-03

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/proj39 Size:1.3T Created:2019-09-29 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2019-12-11 Changed:2019-12-11
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and replace image with its text.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Guidelines direct to NOT paste images.  Paste the source code directly, and use the {} formatting option to specify "<PRE>" like formatting.

Comment: Hey there i changed it up, really sorry still learning. thank you for your patience

Comment: @SalMohamed to be clear, the csv file would have fields (column headings) of `'File Name', size, created, accessed, modified, changed` with data relevant to each in subsequent rows at the specified position?

Comment: Also, does the output have the blank lines shown between records or have you added them for clarity here?

Comment: The output does not have the spaces when looking at it through the terminal, i guess when i copied and pasted it spit it out like that, and yes the columns would need to be File name, size, created, accessed, modified, and changed.

Answer (score 0):

The following `awk` procedure can be used to create a `.csv` output from your data, taking advantage of the rigidly defined structure of the example data given.

for testing purposes, I have saved your data in a file named `data.txt`:

```
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db1 Size:153G Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2018-05-31 Changed:2018-05-31
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db2 Size:1.9T Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2020-04-21 Changed:2022-02-01
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db3 Size:819G Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2017-10-27 Changed:2018-11-13
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db4 Size:702G Created:2018-04-10 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2018-04-03 Changed:2018-05-26
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/dbqa Size:2.7T Created:2020-08-05 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2021-05-22 Changed:2022-09-06
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/proj22 Size:712G Created:2018-08-07 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2018-04-03 Changed:2020-02-28
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/proj26 Size:627G Created:2022-05-25 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2022-06-03 Changed:2022-06-03
File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/proj39 Size:1.3T Created:2019-09-29 Accessed:2022-12-14 Modified:2019-12-11 Changed:2019-12-11
```

Processing the data with the following `awk` procedure:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: ]"}  NR==1{print $1" "$2","$4","$6","$8","$10","$12} {print $3","$5","$7","$9","$11","$13} ' data.txt
```

results in the following output:

```
FileName,Size,Created,Accessed,Modified,Changed
/sasdata/userdata01/db1,153G,2018-04-10,2022-12-14,2018-05-31,2018-05-31
/sasdata/userdata01/db2,1.9T,2018-04-10,2022-12-14,2020-04-21,2022-02-01
/sasdata/userdata01/db3,819G,2018-04-10,2022-12-14,2017-10-27,2018-11-13
/sasdata/userdata01/db4,702G,2018-04-10,2022-12-14,2018-04-03,2018-05-26
/sasdata/userdata01/dbqa,2.7T,2020-08-05,2022-12-14,2021-05-22,2022-09-06
/sasdata/userdata01/proj22,712G,2018-08-07,2022-12-14,2018-04-03,2020-02-28
/sasdata/userdata01/proj26,627G,2022-05-25,2022-12-14,2022-06-03,2022-06-03
/sasdata/userdata01/proj39,1.3T,2019-09-29,2022-12-14,2019-12-11,2019-12-11
```

which can be redirected to a file in the usual way ( `> data.csv` tagged onto the awk procedure above.

**Explanation**

`awk` processes files line-by-line, separating each line (a `record`) into `fields` that, by default, are white-space-separated 'words' in the line. However, the field separator can be reset to split each line at other characters and, in modern versions of awk, can split at more than one character type.

The first part of the awk procedure uses a `BEGIN` block to reset the field separator to be either a space or a colon `FS="[: ]"` (the square brackets apply `OR` to all the characters within).

Next, a block with the conditional pattern /NR==1/ acts on just the first line of the input to extract and output the header values for the csv file. As the line has been split into fields at spaces and colons, "File Name" is fields 1 and 2 (`$1` and `$2`), while "Size" is field 4 and so on.

The next block, having no preceding condition pattern, is applied to every row. It extracts and prints the values relating to each header field by using the appropriate field numbers.

The commas needed to separate the output are printed between the values (awk can automatically insert a defined output field separator but this is not appropriate here as we have to use both fields 1 and 2 of the input to make output field 1).

**Caveat**

The solution given is specific to your example data and should be considered 'fragile' - it will likely break if the structure of the data varies from that shown. It will work in modern version of awk provided that data structure is always used.

**using the command**

If the data is stored in a file, the file can be fed into the procedure as in the example above.
Alternatively, the output of whatever procedure produced the data can be pipped directly into awk like this:

```
your procedure | awk `...
```

**tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0**

#### Edit

**alternative procedure for `awk` versions that don't process multiple field separators**

This alternative uses the default field separator (white space) to extract fields, with a substitution being used to remove non-value parts of each field.

`sub(/^(.)*:/,"",$i)' takes field i and replaces all characters from the start, up to an including the colon, with an empty string, leaving the value part.

In this example, the header row has been stated explicitly rather than extracting header values from the file.

```
awk 'BEGIN {header="File Name, Size, Created, Accessed, Modified, Changed"; print header;} {row=""; for(i=2;i<NF;i++){sub(/^(.)*:/,"",$i); row=row $i", "} sub(/^(.)*:/,"",$NF); row=row $NF; print row}' data.txt
```

This alternative might help if the awk version can't recognise two delimeters at once.

According to the awk manual however, different awk implementations may interpret `^` in a regex differently.

**output using  GNU Awk 5.1.0**

```
File Name, Size, Created, Accessed, Modified, Changed
/sasdata/userdata01/db1, 153G, 2018-04-10, 2022-12-14, 2018-05-31, 2018-05-31
/sasdata/userdata01/db2, 1.9T, 2018-04-10, 2022-12-14, 2020-04-21, 2022-02-01
/sasdata/userdata01/db3, 819G, 2018-04-10, 2022-12-14, 2017-10-27, 2018-11-13
/sasdata/userdata01/db4, 702G, 2018-04-10, 2022-12-14, 2018-04-03, 2018-05-26
/sasdata/userdata01/dbqa, 2.7T, 2020-08-05, 2022-12-14, 2021-05-22, 2022-09-06
/sasdata/userdata01/proj22, 712G, 2018-08-07, 2022-12-14, 2018-04-03, 2020-02-28
/sasdata/userdata01/proj26, 627G, 2022-05-25, 2022-12-14, 2022-06-03, 2022-06-03
/sasdata/userdata01/proj39, 1.3T, 2019-09-29, 2022-12-14, 2019-12-11, 2019-12-11
```

Comment: I put the output in a file and ran the command you suggested but the output was not it, this was the output

root@xizsdap1x:/home/o722823a# awk 'BEGIN{FS="[: ]"}  NR==1{print $1" "$2","$4","$6","$8","$10","$12} {print $3","$5","$7","$9","$11","$13} ' test.csv

File Name:/sasdata/userdata01/db1/reev_fetal_death/fetal_death_2001_2018.sas7bdat  Size:1.6M  Created:2020-08-28  Accessed:2022-12-14  Modified:2020-08-28  Changed:2021-01-11 ,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

,,,,,

Comment: @SalMohamed can you check your awk version by typing `awk --v` in your terminal. Early versions of awk don't allow multiple field-separators to be used and would be unable to use my example. If the output included the awk command, there is likely an error listed there somewhere too. Let me know your awk version number. I will think of an alternative if needed.

Comment: I've edited to include an alternative that does not rely on multiple field separators. Both solutions work for me when copy-pasted from the page here. Good luck

Comment: thank you very much for your help. I am using solaris os so the awk command that comes packaged does not have all the capabilities of the one I use on redhat, I did however find a directory where all the gnu-based commands are stored and awk was one of them. I was able to replicate the exact format using the alternative method. I really appreciate your help

Comment: great, thanks for letting me know as I like to keep track of versions that don't work.